# IQueryable with String.Format and PatIndex

Tags: linq, iqueryable, string.format, patindex

I am facing a issue when i try to used `string.format` on two db entities A, B and then using `SqlFunctions.PatIndex` on them

```
     IQueryable<Data> dataRecords = DbSet<Data> M_Data;
     dataRecords = dataRecords.Where(c => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(sqlFilter, String.Format(A,B)) > 0);
```

its throwing exception  **Linq to entities does not recognize method string.Format**

When i use `AsEnumarable()`

```
dataRecords = dataRecords.AsEnumerable().Where(c => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(sqlFilter, String.Format(A,B)) > 0).AsQueryable();
```

than it's throwing This **function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities**

Can any one suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two method calls:

1. `String.Format`
2. `SqlFunctions.PatIndex`

Problem is, that the first one cannot be transformed into proper SQL query and the second one can only be executed within LINQ to Entities query context. Former makes your first attempt fail, latter breaks second try.

However, I don't see `A` nor `B` be part of the data you query. You should be able to call `string.Format` outside of you query and then use the result:

```
var formattedString = String.Format(A,B);
dataRecords = dataRecords.Where(c => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(sqlFilter, formattedString) > 0);
```

Comment: A,B are the column name of table M_Data